# Chained Payment - delay charge to credit card

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there any option to store credit card information on Paypal servers temporarily when using Adaptive Payments on an IOS app?
With the option of later: 
1) cancelling the transaction
2) running the transaction

My client only wants to charge their customers if they request a service but are not available at their residence at the agreed upon time(no-show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the adaptive payments guide on https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

the only thing that might be relative is

> By default, payments to all receivers in a chained payment are immediate. However, you can choose to delay a payment to a secondary receiver. For example, as primary receiver, you may require secondary receivers to perform some action, such as shipping goods or waiting for expiration of a return period, before making payment. To complete the payment, you must explicitly execute a payment to secondary receivers after the sender pays you. The payment must occur within 90 days, after which you cannot complete the payment as part of the original chained payment.

This would allow you to refund the transaction (if cancelled) or continue with the adaptive payment. Besides that, you cant do an authorization of someones card with adaptive payments.

Hope that helps.